# getStringArrayListExtra returns nullpointerexception for size()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I am trying to use `getStringArrayListExtra()` to get an arrayList of strings passed through an intent. Basically, I get the strings from a listView inside an activity, pass them into an activity, and then pass it into a Service to do what I need it to do. The problem arises when I try to call `.size()`. It throws a nullpointerexception.

Here's the code I've used so far:

FirstActivity:

```
public void chatStart(View v){

    //Clears all duplicates
    Set setItems = new LinkedHashSet(selectedFriend);
    selectedFriend.clear();
    selectedFriend.addAll(setItems);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestScreen.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Friend_List", selectedFriend);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

SecondActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    setContentView(R.layout.testscreen);

    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.friendsList);
    ArrayList<String> itemlist = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("Friend_List");

    for(int i = 0; i<itemlist.size(); i++){

        if(itemlist.get(i) == null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Something Went Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{

            et.append(itemlist.get(i) + " ");

        }

    }

}

public void createStream(View view){

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.friendsList);
    EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);

    ArrayList<String> itemlist2 = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("Friend_List");

    if(et2.getText().toString() != null && et.getText().toString() != null){
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, StreamBuilder.class);

        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Friend_List",itemlist2);
        intent.putExtra("Stream_Title",et.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("Message",et2.getText().toString());

        startService(intent2);

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Fill In All Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



}
```

Service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {

    ArrayList<String> users = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("Friend_List");

    String title = intent.getStringExtra("Stream_Title");


    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) { //Where the nullpointerexception error occurs

        //Do This

    }

    stopSelf()

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}
```

All Help is appreciated.

Comment: why you stop the service after start it?`startService(intent2);
        stopService(intent2);`

Comment: That's a typo. I actually want it to stop after it completes the task in `onStartCommand()`. I'll fix it.

Comment: is `String title = intent.getStringExtra("Stream_Title");` also return null?

Comment: It also returns null. I didn't notice that at first. `Log.d` returned this error on title:




`Unable to start service com.bloom.android.Tools.StreamBuilder@536b5480 with Intent { cmp=com.bloom.android/.Tools.StreamBuilder }: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

Comment: did you already add the service in manifest?

Comment: Yes, my service was registered in the manifest.

Comment: edit your question to include your logcat and manifest

Comment: you are doing wrong with putExtra  and Array, adding values to **intent** instead of **intent2**..

Comment: Is it working now?. You are adding values to wrong intent instance. i.e. intent instead of intent2.

Comment: @bharat this was the problem! changing it to **intent2** fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get the list in SecondActivity?

```
ArrayList<String> itemlist = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("Friend_List");
```

If yes, I believe the method createStream(View v) is defined in the same class, so if that is the case, make the ArrayList above as global and when you start the service pass this one with the Intent.

Let me know if I could be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

You get null point exception when calling `users.size()` => Your `users` in service is null.
It is possibly that you don't get the `ArrayList` succeed, or, you didn't put the `ArrayList` into `Intent` correctly.

In `FirstActivity`, I am confused that what does `setItems` use for? Why don't you directly put `selectedFriend` into `Intent`?